# Where can I find the reason a message was Nack'd?

Tags: ibm-mq

#### Context

I am new to IBM MQ. I am trying to understand why a Consumer is Nack'ing a message. It's worth mentioning that I don't have direct access to the consumer.

#### The problem I am trying to solve

In particular, one of the consumers is Nack'ing a message and putting it back to the Queue. But I am unable to know where to find the reason the message was not acknowledged. Where should I expect this (exception?) to be logged?

I am happy to provide further details if needed.

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "Nack"? Since there's no such thing, really, in MQ. If it's something the consumer application is doing, then the application developer would have to provide details like logs.

Answer (score 1):

There are rare circumstances where the Queue Manager rolls back transactions (all I can think of is to release log space or when it terminated unexpectedly). By far the largest number of cases it is the consuming application which rolls back the transaction, and I believe this is what you also assume when you say it would not acknowledge the message.
To answer the question: get the logs of this application!